# C++: first index of an empty array won't populate its given character with .resize(), but every other character following does

Tags: c++, arrays, string, visual-studio

I'm new to C++ so please forgive me if this is basic.

I have a basic encrypting algorithm below. Everything generally works as it should, except that the encrypted output of the first index of the string 'text' is not appended to the string 'cipher'. Every index following the first is appended as it should.

Any ideas with this one?

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string text = "Do not worry about your difficulties in Mathematics. I can assure you mine are still greater.";
    string cipher;

    int tSize = text.size();
    int cSize = cipher.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < tSize; i++)
    {
        if (isalpha(text[i]))
            if (isupper(text[i]))
            {
                if (text[i] < 'V') cipher.resize(cSize++, text[i] + 4);
                else cipher.resize(cSize++, text[i] - 22);
            }
            else
            {
                if (text[i] < 'v') cipher.resize(cSize++, text[i] + 4);
                else cipher.resize(cSize++, text[i] - 22);
            }
        else cipher.resize(cSize++, text[i]);
    }

    cout << cipher << endl;
}
```

**Output**

```
s rsx asvvc efsyx csyv hmjjmgypxmiw mr Qexliqexmgw. M ger ewwyvi csy qmri evi wxmpp kviexiv.
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the variable `cSize` is initially zero, and you use *post* increment when resizing `cipher`.

Remember that post-increment returns the *old* value, the value before the increment. That means the very first call to `resize` will resize the string with the size zero.

The simple solution is to use *pre* increment, as in `++cSize`, instead. Or initialize `cSize` to `1`.

Comment: Thanks, pre-incrementing solved it! I wasn't aware there was pre- and post-incrementing!